# I am using javascript to create an image slideshow, but the code is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I am using javascript to create an image slideshow, but no images are shown.

What am I doing wrong?

```
window.onLoad(

  window.setInterval(function() {

    var source = ["niepic1.jpg", "niepic.png"];
    var count = 0;
    document.getElementById("cover_main").style.backgroundImage = url(source[count]);
    if (count >= 2) {
      count = 0;
    } else {
      count++;
    }

  }, 5000);

);
```

```
#cover_main {
     background-image: url("");
     height: 45%;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     width:100%;
     height:480px;

}
#cover_main_inside {
    background-color:#A8A8A8 ;
    opacity: 0.76;
    margin-left: 75%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```
<div class="row" id="cover_main">
    <div class="col-3" style=" color:black; background-color:; border-radius:15px;" id="cover_main_inside">
        <form class="form" action="pages/main/aboutteam.html" method="POST">
            <h2 style="margin-left:40px;">Log In:</h2>
            E-mail Address:<br>
            <input id="name" type="email" name="email" placeholder="name@nie.ac.in" required><br><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" required><br><br>
            <input class="input-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Let Me In">
        </form><br>
        <a href="pages/main/profile.html" style="margin-left:35px;">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting no image at all when i am running the html file..

Comment: You also need to post the html you are using. With this is imposible to determine the cause. Perhaps you have the images in the wrong folder as well. Are you sure your images are not in `["images/niepic1.jpg", "images/niepic.png"]`

Comment: they are in the same path.When I am excluding the JS from HTML I am able to get an image, but when I am including the JS its just  blank.

Comment: see it in dev tool,if url is it pointing to right path

Comment: post your html please

Comment: In your function you always define count=0; before doing anything else. The increment on the bottom of the code is always "overwritten"

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code as written - first, I don't think you're calling `window.onload` correctly. Also, move the `count` variable out of the `setInterval` call, or else it will always be 0 when you set the `backgroundImage`. You also don't need to re-set the `source` array, so that can come out of the `setInterval`. Finally, with only 2 elements in your source array, you can reset count if it's greater than 1, since JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed.

```
var count = 0;
var source = ["niepic1.jpg","niepic.png"];

window.onload = function () {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("cover_main").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + source[count] + "')";
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            count = 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the changes, but it gives the same result.Still no image.

Comment: set the background image CSS property as a string rather than a call to the nonexistent `url` function

Answer (score 0):

In your code when write

```
document.getElementById("cover_main").style.backgroundImage = url(source[count]);
```

Here you are referring to the `url` variable or more of `url` function which is not present and breaking your code, so use

```
document.getElementById("cover_main").style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+source[count]+'")';
```

```js
var count = 0;
var source = ["niepic1.jpg", "niepic.png"];

setInterval(function() {
    
    document.getElementById("cover_main").style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+source[count]+'")';
document.getElementById("cover_main").innerHTML = "current background-image style is "+document.getElementById("cover_main").style.backgroundImage;
    count = (count >= 1)? 0 : ++count;
  }, 1000);
```

```css
#cover_main {
     background-image: url("");
     height: 45%;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     width:100%;
     height:480px;

}
#cover_main_inside {
    background-color:#A8A8A8 ;
    opacity: 0.76;
    margin-left: 75%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="cover_main">
    <div class="col-3" style=" color:black; background-color:; border-radius:15px;" id="cover_main_inside">
        <form class="form" action="pages/main/aboutteam.html" method="POST">
            <h2 style="margin-left:40px;">Log In:</h2>
            E-mail Address:<br>
            <input id="name" type="email" name="email" placeholder="name@nie.ac.in" required><br><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" required><br><br>
            <input class="input-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Let Me In">
        </form><br>
        <a href="pages/main/profile.html" style="margin-left:35px;">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```